# How to store certain variable values in a dynamically added control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button which I added programmatically and I want to store certain unique information with every button. I have saved the Name and Text but is there a way to store another string to access later. Below is the code for my button and it's click event.

```
    for (int i = bankaccountsDatagridview.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
                    string buttonName = "individualDepartmentBtn-" + i;
                    FontAwesome.Sharp.IconButton individualDepartmentBtn = new FontAwesome.Sharp.IconButton();
                    individualDepartmentBtn.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                    individualDepartmentBtn.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
                    individualDepartmentBtn.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top;
                    individualDepartmentBtn.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
                    individualDepartmentBtn.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Silver;
                    individualDepartmentBtn.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(224)))), ((int)(((byte)(224)))), ((int)(((byte)(224)))));
                    individualDepartmentBtn.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
                    individualDepartmentBtn.Flip = FontAwesome.Sharp.FlipOrientation.Normal;
                    individualDepartmentBtn.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Roboto", 11.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
                    individualDepartmentBtn.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DimGray;
                    individualDepartmentBtn.IconChar = FontAwesome.Sharp.IconChar.None;
                    individualDepartmentBtn.IconColor = System.Drawing.Color.DimGray;
                    individualDepartmentBtn.IconSize = 25;
                    individualDepartmentBtn.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
                    individualDepartmentBtn.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(10);
                    individualDepartmentBtn.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(30, 0, 0, 0);
                    individualDepartmentBtn.Name = bankaccountsDatagridview.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    individualDepartmentBtn.Rotation = 0D;
                    individualDepartmentBtn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(192, 30);
                    individualDepartmentBtn.TabIndex = 1;
                    individualDepartmentBtn.Text = bankaccountsDatagridview.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    individualDepartmentBtn.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
                    individualDepartmentBtn.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
                    navigationPanel.Controls.Add(individualDepartmentBtn);
                    individualDepartmentBtn.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(individualBankBtnDown);
   }
```

Click Event:

```
    private void individualBankBtnDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        bankTitle = ((FontAwesome.Sharp.IconButton)sender).Name.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: You could use the [`Tag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tag?view=net-5.0) property.

Comment: @stuartd Right after leaving stackoverflow I found the tag property. Thank you so much for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Tag` property. For example:

```
individualDepartmentBtn.Tag = "My String";
```

You can store any object within `Tag` and not only strings.

Note that you could also use the `var` keyword and an object initializer to make your code a little bit more readable:

```
var individualDepartmentBtn = new FontAwesome.Sharp.IconButton
{
    BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White,
    Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand,
    Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top,
    ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have used Tag property and it's working like charm.